How to spawn a single thread with OpenMP (like a std::thread()) and use "#pragma omp single" and "#pragma omp for" afterwards?
I would simply like to spawn a background thread, like std::thread, but just with OpenMP.
Is this possible?
If yes, how ist it done?
To better explain what I want to achieve, here the C++ Code of what I want to do:
//05.06.2024
//How to spawn a single thread with OpenMP (like a std::thread()) and use "#pragma omp single" and 
//"#pragma omp for" afterwards? This here does not work! (as expected)
//OS: Linux Mint 21.3, Kernel: 6.5.0-35-generic x86_64 bits
//compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

// g++ -O2 openmp_single_bkgtask_test.cpp -fopenmp 

#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

void backgroundWork()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout<<"background work!"<<std::endl;
        usleep(1e6);
    }   
}

int main()
{           
    omp_set_num_threads(8); 
        
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        #pragma omp task
        backgroundWork();
                
        while(true)
        {
            #pragma omp single
            std::cout<<"loading data"<<std::endl;
            //++++++++++
            //prog never comes beyond this point, because "#pragma omp single" is waiting after
            //"loading data" for the <task>-thread to finish (which of course does not happen
            //++++++++++
            #pragma omp for
            for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
            {
                std::cout<<"processing data "<<i<<std::endl;
            }                   
        }       
    }           
    
    return 0;
}

I know this will not work, as the omp single instruction will wait for all threads, but one is "missing" in the "task", so it "works" as expected.
But how can I spawn a thread in OpenMP?

AFAIR omp master does not wait. Why not use omp single nowait like you did before? Anyway, the initial model for OpenMP is the fork-join model. If you want to do async operations or daemon threads, then OpenMP is not really made for that. Still, you can use tasks for computing operations (not much for real threads as you should avoid communications between tasks as opposed to threads). Once you start to use tasks, you should use them everywhere in the target parallel section since tasks does not mix well with the classical for. There is taskloop for that.

Once you start to do tasks, you should avoid barriers and global synchronization if possible, especially in your case (due to the "background work"). Global synchronizations tends not to scale anyway on many-core systems (and be inefficient with task parallelism). One solution is to use task dependencies. Another is to use hierarchical tasks, that is tasks in tasks. You can wait all task in a current task with taskwait. In your case, the second is certainly simpler and more efficient (since there is no interaction between the background task and others).

Here is solution using only tasks, and an omp single pragma for the whole parallel region:
int main()
{           

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    {
        #pragma omp task
        backgroundWork();
                
        int v = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            v++;
            #pragma omp critical
            std::cout<<v<<" loading data"<<std::endl;
            #pragma omp taskloop
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                usleep(1e5);
                #pragma omp critical
                std::cout<<v<<" processing data "<<i<<std::endl;
            }                   
        }
    }           
    
    return 0;
}

As suggested by Jerôme Richard, the omp for is replaced by an omp taskloop. The critical pragmas just aim at a better formatted text output.
Since the thread executing the single region does nothing during the taskloop execution, you may use one more thread compared to the number of cores. And another one in the case the background task does almost nothing.
Note that there is actually no guarantee that the background task is executed first (the OpenMP runtime is allowed to schedule the tasks on its own), although in practice it will highly likely be. An alternative that guarantees the execution is based on sections:
int main()
{           

    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        backgroundWork();
                
        #pragma omp section
        {
            int v = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                v++;
                #pragma omp critical
                std::cout<<v<<" loading data"<<std::endl;
                #pragma omp taskloop
                for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                {
                    usleep(1e5);
                    #pragma omp critical
                    std::cout<<v<<" processing data "<<i<<std::endl;
                }   
            }                
        }
    }           
    
    return 0;
}

Third solution with sections and nested parallelism:
int main()
{           

    omp_set_nested(1);

    #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp section
        backgroundWork();
                
        #pragma omp section
        {
            int v = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                v++;
                #pragma omp critical
                std::cout<<v<<" loading data "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<std::endl;
                #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
                for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                {
                    usleep(1e5);
                    #pragma omp critical
                    std::cout<<v<<" processing data "<<i<<" "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<std::endl;
                }   
            }                
        }
    }           
    
    return 0;
}


Thank you PierU for your help. I do not know if your first version will work correctly, as I remember a question from me some years ago link. But the second version with sections works. I have to add the number of tasks (#pragma omp taskloop num_tasks(7)) that it works as planned. (No idea what default value is, but I need to use  "n-1" if omp_set_num_threads(n) is used, for more or less efficient load balancing.

BUT, I would like to use "#pragma omp for" with all its nice schedule parameters, like "dynamik", "guided" and "chunksize".
I think this omp taskloop construct is just like "#pragma omp for schedule(static)". Is there no way to use "#pragma omp for" as in my example?

@martin7743 I would say that taskloop is more similar (but not equivalent at all) to for schedule(dynamic), as a given iteration can be executed by any available thread. You can control how the iterations are grouped by using the grainsize and num_tasks

If you really want to use the omp for worksharing construct, you have to use nested parallelism, by defining a nested parallel region inside the 2nd section. See my updated answer.

Thanks again! Your third version works fine. I moved the "parallel" clause out of the while loop (and added the single clause, as seen in my original question), to save as much time within the while loop as possible. But it looks overcomplicated, for such a simple "Task" of spawning a task. I am still testing some ideas.

I tested some taskloops and learned, at least on my gcc version, that the taskloop is more or less schedule(static). The number of loops is divided by num_tasks, and each task is getting  this chunksize of iterations. Even if one task is finished with his complete work, and other tasks still have some iterations to do, the finished task stays idle. So not the behaviour of schedule(dynamic).

It looks like you're right and that by default gfortran/gomp groups the iterations in a similar way to the static schedule. We have to play with grainsize/numtasks to get the desired behavior. The default behavior is not specified by the OpenMP specification: "If neither a grainsize nor num_tasks clause is present, the number of loop tasks generated and the number of logical loop iterations assigned to these tasks is implementation defined."

The OpenMP 6.0 solution is to use a free-agent task.
int main()
{           
    omp_set_num_threads(8); 

    #pragma omp task threadset(pool)
    {
        // if the task is not executed as free-agent task, we would stall here.
        assert(omp_is_free_agent()); 
        backgroundWork();
    }

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        while(true)
        {
            #pragma omp single
            std::cout<<"loading data"<<std::endl;

            #pragma omp for
            for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
            {
                std::cout<<"processing data "<<i<<std::endl;
            }                   
        }       
    }           
        
    return 0;
}

The task will be executed on a separate thread, unless you start the application explicitly with 0 free-agent threads. If you want to synchronize the exit from the loop, make sure to use atomic read for the while condition.
OpenMP 6.0 is expected for end of this year. I'm not aware of an implementation in a released compiler.

Thank you Joachim, for your interesting information. So does this mean, that at the moment there is no way with openmp to spawn a thread outside "#omp parallel" and therefore some tricky constructs are needed?

Right, at the moment there are only these hacks to spawn extra threads in OpenMP. You can of cause always spawn C++ threads. Since OpenMP is fully compatible with recent C++ standards, this should always work unless there are implementation bugs.
